# develop video player on android to support HLS

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I am trying to develop own video player that supports HLS(http live streaming) from 2.1.

I have tried vitamio but it requires that we install vitamio plugin which is around 3.2 MB.So trying to develop own video player.

I have been searching android source code to check how m3u8 file format is being supported on 3.0 onwards but have been unsuccessful so far.

It would be helpful if someone points me in the right direction. What classes do I have to check?

Answer (score 1):

VLC Supports HLS but just barely. There is a product called NexPlayer which supported HLS all the way down to 1.6, but its paid only.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be helpful if someone points me in the right direction. What
>   classes do I have to check?

I'm sure you have definitely found the HLS source code by now,

but this is also for others who will attend this page.

[HLS source code on Android 4.4.2, written in C++.](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/httplive/)